# Format Hour from 1 to 24 Instead of 0 to 23

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, vb.net, time-format

I am using **Now.Hour** to return an integer for a query. Here is my sql query:

```
 SELECT * FROM DATABASE.dbo.STORE_LIVE WHERE DELIVERY_HOUR=Now.Hour
```

However, at 12 midnight, my query is not returning any row since Now.Hour only returns '0' but the DELIVERY_HOUR in the database has a range of 1 to 24.

In MSDN Time Format, these are the only available formats:

**"H"**

- The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 0 to 23.
- 6/15/2009 1:45:30 AM -> 1
- 6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM -> 13

**"HH"**

- The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 00 to 23.
- 6/15/2009 1:45:30 AM -> 01
- 6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM -> 13

How should I customized Now.Hour to return from 1 to 24 without resorting to a conditional statement for interval 0 or 23?

Thanks

Comment: So you want `6/15/2009 12:45:30 AM -> 24`, correct? Between midnight and 1 AM the hour will be 24 then at 1 AM the hour becomes 1, then at 11 PM the hour is 23 and then your day changes over and your first hour of the day is 24 again?

Comment: Hi Scott! Yes. that is my objective. all of our databases has that configuration too so it's a little bit troublesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you create an extension method which returns 1 - 24 instead of 0 - 23.

Put this code into a **module**:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

<Extension()>
Private Function GetCustomHour(aDate As Date) As Integer
    Dim hour = aDate.Hour
    Select Case hour
        Case 0 : Return 24
        Case Else : Return hour
    End Select
End Function
```

Then in your code:

Instead of `Now.Hour` use `Now.GetCustomHour`

---

However, I would strongly advise that you change your database to store valid times as this is only going to cause more problems along the way (there is no such hour of the day as 24)

Comment: Thank you! I am now using your code! I would like to change the database too. But I am not the owner of the database. I would suggest that though. :D